# Dual OS goes into infinite reboot

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, bootloader

I have both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my Laptop. For some reason, windows had an error, so it started the repair tool. This was taking a while and so I cancelled it. Now my GRUB screen is gone, when I load up the computer it goes into an infinite reboot state. I can still access the BIOS and Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 both still seem to be there (I am writing this from Ubuntu 11.10, which I have on a bootable DVD). Obviously the last resort is to remove everything and just use Ubuntu, but it would be much nicer to have them both fixed. Is there a way to re-install the GRUB screen or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reinstall grub and that would fix the problem I guess. http://sosaysharis.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-using-ubuntu/

Comment: When I run the 'fdisk' command, I get this output:

'Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xbbcd25f4

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   237185023   118489088    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       237187070   588070911   175441921    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       588070912   625137663    18533376   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda5       237187072   439467132   101140030+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       439468032   581861375    71196672   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       581863424   588070911     3103744   82  Linux swap / Solaris'

Comment: I'll assume that Linux is on '/dev/sda6/' and not '/dev/sda3/'. I know it should be kinda obvious from the labelling of the drives, but the fact that partition 3 is extended i making me wonder.

Comment: Why not try mounting them and see the files so that you can confirm which one is the Linux partition? :)

Comment: Ok, I think I've almost got this. It's just that when I run 'code'sudo grub-install _root-directory=/home/ubuntu/temp /dev/sda6'code' I get an error message saying 'More than one install devices?'.

Comment: Hold on! First of all, it is "--root-directory". And the last argument should be your hard disk's name and here it is /dev/sda and not /dev/sda6.

Comment: A thousand blessings upon you sir! With your help I've avoided what could have been a crisis :D Now i know what to do should something like this happen again - thanks :)